# multiple onclicks for one function

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm trying to write a photo gallery page where there are small icons of photo's below and when you click on them they enlarge into the main photo screen. only I'm having trouble trying to get the javascript to do what I want. Can anyone help me please?

here's my code so far:

```
<?php
                $host = "localhost";
                $user = "root";
                $pwd = "";
                $db_name = "gallery";

                mysql_connect($host, $user, $pwd)or die("cannot connect"); 
                mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");


                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM foto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
                $id = 'id';
                $foto = 'foto';


                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
                {
                    echo "<img class='littleshow'"."id='foto".$rows[$id]."'src='".$rows[$foto]."' onclick='Bigscreen(foto".$rows[$id].")'></img>";
                } //the onclick generates onclick="bigscreen(foto1)" and does this again 4 times on the other objects generating foto1,foto2,foto3,foto4
                ?>
                <div id='bigshowcase'></div>
```

and my Javascript so far:

```
function Bigscreen () {      
        var div0 = document.getElementById('bigshowcase');

        var images = new array();
        images[0] = div0.style.backgroundImage = "url(pic/camera.jpg)";
        images[1] = div0.style.backgroundImage = "url(pic/dsc_4255.jpg)";
        images[2] = div0.style.backgroundImage = "url(pic/dsc_4373.jpg)";
        images[3] = div0.style.backgroundImage = "url(pic/dsc01209.jpg)";

        foto1 = images[0]
        foto2 = images[1]
        foto3 = images[2]
        foto4 = images[3]
}
```

I know very little about javascript so most of this is probably wrong.
thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

replace this line:

```
echo "<img class='littleshow'"."id='foto".$rows[$id]."'src='".$rows[$foto]."' onclick='Bigscreen(foto".$rows[$id].")'></img>";
```

with this:

```
echo "<img class='littleshow'"."id='foto".$rows[$id]."'src='".$rows[$foto]."' onclick='Bigscreen(this)'></img>";
```

and change `Bigscreen` function to:

```
function Bigscreen(img) {
    document.getElementById('bigshowcase').innerHTML ='<img src="' + img.src + '" />';
}
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#bigshowcase img{max-width:600px;max-height:600px;}
</style>
```

hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

note that jQuery is always nicer:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'img.littleshow', function(){
        $('#bigshowcase').html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" />');
    });
});
</script>
```

will do the job.

Comment: I agree, jQuery.  Nice solutions tho... Either should work just fine.

Comment: Yes it is. Too bad I don't speak it. +1

Comment: did you get any javascript error?
can you try the second approach?

Comment: i get a php error uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. it says the error is one line 32 wich is the opening of my php script

Comment: this is a js error, look for line number in the OUTPAGE PAGE (view source), not in your code file

Comment: the error is on the echo line of the php code probably the last part because it outputs onclick="Bigscreen(\" pic="" dsc_4255.jpg\')'="">

Comment: now i get a javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'innerHTML' of object #<HTMLDivElement> is not a function

Comment: thanks alot :) it works now.. only the image is its normal size (3000x2000) can i fix this using css or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the element you clicked on as a variable of a function:

> ```
> <img id="mainPic">
> <img id="thumbImage" src="<url>" onclick="SetPic(this)">
>
>
>
> var mainPic = document.getElementById("mainPic");
>
> function SetPic(thumbPic)
> {
>    mainPic.src = thumbPic.src;
> }
> ```